# Move windows from one partition to another on the same drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd

While installing windows, I created a 66 gig partition for windows 10, and another 50 gigs for programs, but accidentally I installed windows in the 50 gig partition. And now I can't even extend C drive because the bigger partition is on the left of C. Here is the partition structure.

```
System Reserved (50 MB)| 66 GB (unallocated)| Windows C (50 gb)| 522MB (Recovery Partition)| 3 gb unallocated
```

1: Is it possible to move windows from 50 gb partition to 66 gb one? Without any paid tools?

2: If i have to reinstall windows, i was hopping the C partition and the 50/53 gb 2nd partition will be next to each other so that i can extend c drive if needed. Is this possible??

Comment: You're talking about a 16 GB difference. Is all the trouble of trying to relocate or reinstall Windows worth that?

Comment: Hmm, fair point. Windows is a fresh install, so I already have to install programs if they cannot be accessed from old drive.

Comment: @AbdulAhad It wasn't clear from the wording, but are you using the Programs partition to symlink the two program folders on Windows to?

Comment: Also note that Windows hogs drive space, and even 66 GB will likely be insufficient after apps are installed and an update or two completed. Aside from the Windows folder, Registry and other data takes up room. Linux would work well in little space, but a full Windows install, not for long. You might try removing all unwanted MS and other apps,  but get a larger drive if you plan to keep the machine.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to clone Windows to the other partition, but is not worth
the trouble.

It would be simpler to reduce the size of D:, which will create
unallocated space following it. Then move C: upward over this space,
which will move the unallocated space below C:, so then you can enlarge
it by this amount.

You would need a third-party partition editor like GParted that you
can boot to move partitions (this can't be done from inside Windows).
The final resizing of C: should be done from Windows after booting it.

Before doing these manipulations, better take a backup of the whole
disk using a product such as
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.aomeitech.com/ab/standard.html)
and also
[Create AOMEI Bootable CD/DVD/USB Based on Windows PE](https://www.ubackup.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html)
to ensure being able to return to the current state in case of
emergency. Ensure that the boot USB works and can see the saved image
before doing the partition editing.

Comment: To be clear, moving C upward will put C to the left of unallocated space (or D)? Currently it is on right.

Comment: To the left - the move is *over* the unallocated space.